# PHP For (certain array keys) loop

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Editing this question entirely, for future learners.

I initially asked if a single `while` function could replace the code below. I didn't realize `while` doesn't increment automatically like `foreach`, so no. Great answers below on better solutions using either `array_slice()` or the classic `for` loop.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key < 25) {
        echo '<img src="'.$value.'/preview_image.jpg">';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual array?

Comment: state the issue clearly

Comment: `foreach (array_filter($array, function($key) { return $key < 25; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY) as $key => $value) {`

Comment: @MarkBaker `array_slice($array, 0, 25)` is the better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would still have to increment the key, plus the key would have to be uniform to work.

Foreach works on the set and is more resilient against gaps in the range. Iterating over a set with for example 1,2 and 4 as keys, works great with foreach.

Another method could be:

```
for ($i=0;$i<25;$i++) etc
```

This checks the end conditions straight away, but does not take gaps into account, which could lead to extra code in the for loop itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple **for loop**

like this

```
for($i = 0; $i < 25; $i++)
{
    echo '<img src="'.$array[$i].'/preview_image.jpg">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `array_slice()` solution.
Also you should use **Alternative syntax for control structures** for displaying HTML.

[PHP: Alternative syntax for control structures - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

```
<?php

/* Logic Part */

$array = [...];
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 25);

// You MUST apply this function before echoing user inputs
// for the sake of security reasons.
function h($s)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

/* HTML Part */

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>

<div>
<?php foreach ($array as $value): ?>
    <img src="<?=h($value)?>/preview_image.jpg">
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You effectively want to retrieve the first 24 lines from a file.

There are many ways to do that.

This is one way:

```
$file = new SplFileObject($path);
$file->setFlags($file::DROP_NEW_LINE);
$head = new LimitIterator($file, 0, 24);
foreach ($head as $value) {
    ...
}
```

The benefit is that you get a plain variable to foreach over that provides the data you need. This works with the *Decortator* pattern and is pretty flexible.

If the file has less than 24 lines (records), the foreach will finish earlier.

Also this code would not read the whole file into memory only to provide the first 24 lines.

Comment: It's a nice solution if we handle large files with `SplFileObject` or databases with `PDOStatement`. If we handle small arrays, however, it just brings non-beneficial redundancy.

Comment: What non-beneficial redundancy is for the one is more modular for the other. More decorators are easy to apply here, also arrays don't have the object interface.